# Branch named <96>d in Git

Tags: git

While executing the git branch command, <96>d is listed at the end, with <96> being highlighted. 
Though it doesn't seem to be a valid branch, does it indicate something? How do I delete it? 
I am using git on Unix.

```
> git branch
branch1
branch2
**<96>**d
```

While trying to delete it, an error is seen

```
> git branch -d <96>d
Error: Branch '<96>d' not found.
> git branch -d 96d
Error: Branch '96d' not found.
> git branch -d "<96>d"
Error: Branch '<96>d' not found.
```

Comment: What makes you think that it is NOT a branch?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a valid branch as I have not created it, nor is it present at the remote server.

Comment: Maybe `<96>` is representing a special character? If it's decimal, it would be a backtick/grave, but more likely it's hexadecimal and it's representing a "Start of Protected Area" control code.

Comment: If this is a Windows machine, `\x96d` would be `–d`, where the dash is a U+2013; that's what you'd get if you ran `git branch -d`, but with an en-dash.

Comment: The `<96>` part is a result of your pager realizing that the character whose code is 0x96 cannot be displayed correctly. Instead, it prints the hexadecimal value in angle brackets, highlighted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Bash,

```
git branch -d $'\x96d'
```

If this is a Windows machine, \x96d would be '–d', where the dash is a U+2013; that's what you'd get if you previously ran `git branch –d`, after copying a web page that used an en-dash.

Comment: Thank you, this helped. I think it came after using a different keyboard

Answer (score 1):

The branch name contains special characters (from the shell perspective) which need to be quoted when you try to reference it (e.g. during creation as in this example):

```
[user:~/git-test] git branch "<96>d"
[user:~/git-test] git branch
* 0.1
  <96>d
  master
```

You likely created it unaware and in error, trying to do something else. Depending on what it contains you might want to merge, rebase or simply delete it.

If you are sure that deletion is safe and doesn't delete any data you want to retain, do so like you did, but quote the name:

```
git branch -d "<96>d"
```

Comment: Previously, I forgot to mention and I just updated the question. <96> is always highlighted while listing the branch name, but d is not highlighted